# Asp.net mvc ajax running one more time

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I use `Ajax.BeginForm` form post.

But when I click the button quickly more than one. Process work more than one. `RefreshPosts();` script when work, will reset form elements.

Controller:

```
public string SharePost(FormCollection form)
{
        var singleUser = _repUsers.GetUserWithCookie(GetCookie(_set.userCookieName));
        string content = Request.Form["statusText"];
        _opPosts.AddPost(content, singleUser.UserId);
        _opUsers.AddFeed(1, singleUser.UserFirstName, singleUser.UserSurName);
        Session["PostDate"] = DateTime.Now;
        return "Başarıyla paylaştık." + "<script>  refreshPosts(); </script>";

}
```

View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SharePost", "Post", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "result", OnSuccess = "postSuccess", LoadingElementId = "loading" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button on Submit clicked. This can be done using JQuery/Java Script.
Look at [this example](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/05/disable-submit-button-on-form-submit.html) on how to do this.